# Testing whether an ordered infinite stream contains a value

Tags: scala, stream, primes

I have an infinite Stream of primes `primeStream` (starting at 2 and increasing). I also have another stream of Ints `s` which increase in magnitude and I want to test whether each of these is prime.

What is an efficient way to do this? I could define

```
def isPrime(n: Int) = n == primeStream.dropWhile(_ < n).head
```

but this seems inefficient since it needs to iterate over the whole stream each time.

Implementation of `primeStream` (shamelessly copied from elsewhere):

```
  val primeStream: Stream[Int] =
  2 #:: primeStream.map{ i =>
    Stream.from(i + 1)
    .find{ j =>
      primeStream.takeWhile{ k => k * k <= j }
        .forall{ j % _ > 0 }
    }.get
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is about implementing isPrime, then you should do as suggested by rossum, even with division costing more than equality test, and with primes being more dense for lower values of n, it would be asymptotically much faster. Moreover, it is very fast when testing non primes which have a small divisor (most numbers have)

It may be different if you want to test primality of elements of another increasing Stream. You may consider something akin to a merge sort. You did not state how you want to get your result, here as a stream of Boolean, but it should not be too hard to adapt to something else.

```
/** 
 *  Returns a stream of boolean, whether element at the corresponding position
 *  in xs belongs in ys. xs and ys must both be increasing streams.
 */
def belong[A: Ordering](xs: Stream[A], ys: Stream[A]): Stream[Boolean] = {
   if (xs.isEmpty) Stream.empty
   else if (ys.isEmpty) xs.map(_ => true)
   else Ordering[A].compare(xs.head, ys.head) match {
     case less if less < 0 => false #:: belong(xs.tail, ys)
     case equal if equal == 0 => true #:: belong(xs.tail, ys.tail)
     case greater if greater > 0 => belong(xs, ys.tail)
   }
}
```

So you may do `belong(yourStream, primeStream)`

Yet it is not obvious that this solution will be better than a separate testing of primality for each number in turn, stopping at square root. Especially if yourStream is fast increasing compared to primes, so you have to compute many primes in vain, just to keep up. And even less so if there is no reason to suspect that elements in yourStream tend to be primes or have only large divisors.

Answer (score 4):

1. You only need to read your prime stream as far as `sqrt(s)`.
2. As you retrieve each `p` from the prime stream check if `p` evenly divides `s`.

This will give you a trial division method of prime checking.

Comment: Good ideas - this will certainly help with this particular problem. I wonder if more generally there is a good way of searching infinite increasing streams.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the general question of determining whether an ordered finite list consisted entirely of element of an ordered but infinite stream:

The simplest way is

```
candidate.toSet subsetOf infiniteList.takeWhile( _ <= candidate.last).toSet
```

but if the candidate is large, that requires a lot of space and it is O(n log n) instead O(n) like it could be.  The O(n) way is

```
def acontains(a : Int, b : Iterator[Int]) : Boolean = {
  while (b hasNext) {
    val c = b.next
    if (c == a) {
       return true
    }
    if (c > a) {
       return false
    }
  }
  return false
}

def scontains(candidate: List[Int], infiniteList: Stream[Int]) : Boolean = {
  val it = candidate.iterator
  val il = infiniteList.iterator
  while (it.hasNext) {
     if (!acontains(it.next, il)) {
       return false
     }
  }
  return true
}
```

(Incidentally, if some helpful soul could propose a more Scalicious way to write the foregoing, I'd appreciate it.)

**EDIT:**

In the comments, the inestimable Luigi Plinge pointed out that I could just write:

```
def scontains(candidate: List[Int], infiniteStream: Stream[Int]) = {
    val it = infiniteStream.iterator
    candidate.forall(i => it.dropWhile(_ < i).next == i) 
}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I wanted to do, but in your `acontains` method can be replaced by `b.dropWhile(_ < a).next == a` (remember `b` is infinite). Your second loop can be replaced by a `forall`. So together you have `it.forall(i => il.dropWhile(_ < i).next == i)`

Comment: D'oh.  Amazing what only a slight misconception of a function's definition can do.  I had in my head that `dropWhile` would also drop the first element that failed and that `forAll` was a variant of `forEach`.  Incidentally, it didn't compile with `next`, I needed `head`.

Comment: And, @LuigiPlinge, what *did* you want to do.

Comment: With the above I'm still assuming you define `it` and `il` as iterators (iterators don't have a `head` method). I thought that was the point of your post... if you don't use iterators, you have to check over the whole infinite stream each time. It should be OK to use iterators so long as both streams are increasing. As for what I wanted to do, the second stream `s` is also (potentially) infinite, so I need a way of checking each value **efficiently** (i.e. not traversing over the whole stream each time). It's tricky to use iterators for this - recursion seems to be the answer (see didierd's)

Comment: Double d'oh.  Fixed in the answer.  This may not be tricky, I may just be stupid.